# ASP.NET MVC - Multiple inserting into database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel

I'm bulding an ASP.NET MVC web app using the Razor engine. Before explaining my issue, I'd like to explain you the context. I've an Users table and a Group_Tests table. An user can subscribe to a group of tests by mentioning the hours of notification (AM and/or PM) and the frequency (10 times per day). Here's the model (build with Entity Framework from my database) :

[image]

The thing is, I want my users to subscribe to test groups by choosing AM or PM (would be checkboxes) and validate it. It could be more than one group. However, I don't know how to do it. I can easily imagine that I've to create a ViewModel and into my View, doing a foreach loop on my Group_Tests table to add a row of subscription for each existing group.

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 0):

> I can easily imagine that I've to create a ViewModel and into my View, doing a foreach loop on my Group_Tests table to add a row of subscription for each existing group.

You've pretty much got it. But to be honest, we can't help you if you don't post your attempts.

Unless there is a specification requiring users to be able to subscribe to ALL Group_Tests at once, I'd opt for having them choose the desired group_test from something like a dropdownlist rather than rendering an object for every type of Group_Test conceivable. That way, they can subscribe to each Group_Test individually.

If it's really required to subscribe for everything at once, you're on the right track.